# Passing data between two different Salesforce Orgs

Tags: apex, integration, webservices

A noob to SF here.

I was wondering whether it is possible to send data from one dev org to another org via a webservice call.

I have two dev envs (D1 & D2).
D2 has a REST Class defined which can accept a creation request of a custom object record.
From D1, I would like to invoke the POST API of the D2 REST class.

Is it possible ?
Can someone throw me some pointers to do the same ?

Comment: You may have done this already, but check out the REST API documentation on  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/  provided you have authentication and endpoints setup correctly then it should work.

Comment: Was not aware of this guide...appreciate it...can you put that as answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: there is also salesforcetosalesforce (s2s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have done this already, but check out the REST API documentation on salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest provided you have authentication and endpoints setup correctly then it should work.